# BizTalk Server TMS Warning 12223

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2016

I am unable to make this warning go away, it is logged about every 5 minutes on our BizTalk servers.

> Failed refreshing token. Details: AADSTS500341: The user account [GUID] has been deleted from the [GUID] directory. 
>   To sign into this application, the account must be added to the directory.
>   Trace ID: [GUID]
>   Correlation ID: [GUID]
>   Timestamp: 2020-02-04 14:00:17Z

It is correct that a user was removed from the directory, in the port it was then replaced by another user, and this is the token we would like to refresh, going forward.

It was possible to select, Forget (For the deleted account)

I have also tried removing the port all together, and creating it again.
I have tried restarting TMS and the BizTalk Host Instance.
I have tried restarting the server.

I believe somewhere a record is being kept of the deleted account, and I need to know how to get that removed, so TMS will stop trying to refresh the token.

Comment: Did you get any further with this?

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to clear all the credentials and reinstall TMS you can unconfigure TMS and delete the TMS service and then delete the affiliate applications related to TMS. Be aware that all set credentials will be deleted so you need to add the passwords (logon) again.

```
"C:\Program Files\Common Files\Enterprise Single Sign-On\ssomanage.exe" -deleteapp 13f3c6e3-46af-4775-a7de-406a3c2bcab1
"C:\Program Files\Common Files\Enterprise Single Sign-On\ssomanage.exe" -deleteapp 533F6CA2-2934-4B83-A5D2-E22230B44880
```

Then reinstall the TMS service again and configure it.

Earlier versions had missing dependency on EntSSO which could cause timing issue if TMS starts before EntSSO service. Make sure this startup dependency order is set also in case it was missing:

```
sc config BizTalkServerTMS depend= ENTSSO
```

There has been fixes for some issues with O365/TMS in BizTalk 2020 CU5 so good to apply this if on BizTalk 2020.

I have seen some issues related with TLS 1.2 not being default where initial request succeeds, but subsequent token refresh fails with no retry. So I would make sure to have:

:: Install .NET Framework 4.8 (if lower)

:: Add .NET SchUseStrongCrypto setting set to 1 for both 32-bit and 64-bit applications

```
reg add HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v4.0.30319 /v SchUseStrongCrypto /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f /reg:32
reg add HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v4.0.30319 /v SchUseStrongCrypto /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f /reg:64
```

:: Add .NET SystemDefaultTlsVersions setting set to 1 for both 32-bit and 64-bit applications

```
reg add HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v4.0.30319 /v SystemDefaultTlsVersions /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f /reg:32
reg add HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v4.0.30319 /v SystemDefaultTlsVersions /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f /reg:64
```

You can also enable more TMS trace + System.Net trace and also try later Microsoft.Identity.Client (download/extract from NuGet and update .config)

System.Net trace:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/how-to-configure-network-tracing

Microsoft.BizTalk.TokenStore.Service.exe.config change

```
  <appSettings>
    <add key="DebugMode" value="True"/>
    <add key="RefreshInterval" value="5"/>
  </appSettings>
  <system.net>
    <connectionManagement>
      <add address="*" maxconnection="20"/>
    </connectionManagement>
  </system.net>
  <system.diagnostics>
    <trace autoflush="false" indentsize="4">
      <listeners>
        <add name="myListener" type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener" initializeData="Microsoft.BizTalk.TokenStore.Service.Log.txt" />
        <remove name="Default" />
      </listeners>
    </trace>
  </system.diagnostics>
<!--
    <runtime>
        <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
            <probing privatePath="BizTalk Assemblies;Developer Tools;Transform Components;Tracking;Tracking\interop" />
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Identity.Client" publicKeyToken="0a613f4dd989e8ae" culture="neutral" />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="4.0.0.0-4.65535.65535.65535" newVersion="4.47.2.0" />
            </dependentAssembly>
        </assemblyBinding>
    </runtime>
-->
```